# MIPS - performing block copy of words without using pseudo instruction (homework)

Tags: assembly, mips

I have given a work to do which is writing a function of assembly code to perform block copy (which copies a block of words from one address in memory to another address) but I still do not get the meaning of block copy in assembly code.

I am guessing, for example, if I perform block copy at $t0,
would one block be every 4th of the memory? 4($t0)

currently I have to make a function to copy 400 words from address 0x30000 to 0x50000

Answer (score 3):

since you know the size of memory block, and presumably the starting point alongside with the targeted memory location, you need to load the words from the starting point(lw), do whatever you want(if you need to manipulate those words) and store it to the requested memory place. and as you said you are going to increment the memory pointer by 4.Be advised...you can only use 16-bit offsets in lw otherwise you need to use lw with big op which is a pseudo instruction...there are translations for it though...

Comment: ok firstly, i want to make a function to perform block copy. Arguments are source address, destination address and the number of words to copy. Can you demonstrate the code to me please?